# Trying to thread.sleep one part of the code but it effects the whole thing

Tags: java, multithreading, button, label, try-catch

I am trying to make a character move for an attack then move back once the attack happens. I tried to do a `thread.sleep` with the first move before, then the attack and moving back after but it just effects the whole code as if it was before everything instead of being in the middle.

I checked many similar questions and none of them worked or applied to what I was looking for.

```
JButton btnAttack = new JButton("Attack");
    btnAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        int theehp = currentehp;
        int yourhp = maxhp;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int damage = 0;
                    //moves to sleep
                label.move(300, 50);

            damage = (int) (Math.random()* 4 + 1);
            theehp = theehp - damage;
            ehplbl.setText(String.valueOf(theehp));
            ehp.setValue(theehp);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //moves back
            label.move(39,46);

            if (theehp <= 0){
                combat.this.setVisible(false);
                clip.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You win!");

            }else{
            damage = (int) (Math.random()* 2 + 1);
            yourhp = yourhp - damage;
            hp.setValue(yourhp);
            lblhp.setText(String.valueOf(yourhp));}
            if (yourhp <=0){
                combat.this.setVisible(false);
                clip.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "You lose!");

            }
        };
    });
    btnAttack.setBounds(39, 393, 108, 61);
    panel.add(btnAttack);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread.sleep() will literally stop the current Thread from running anything, whatsoever, for that amount of time.

If you want other work to be done at the same time that thread is sleeping, you have to put that work on another thread.  Research **Executors** and similar things to see how to create multiple threads and manage them properly.

Note that unless you have 2+ threads running, your program is never doing more than one thing at a time (at least in terms of business logic, a JVM does a lot in the background on its own threads).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what John Humphreys said:

The thread that calls `actionPerformed(...)` is the swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  It's the thread that handles all user input, and performs all drawing on the screen.

As John H. said, `Thread.sleep()` puts the calling thread to sleep.  So, if you call it from within an `actionPerformed()` method, you are putting the EDT to sleep.  Your application will be unable to respond to any user input or, to show anything happening on the screen until the sleep() returns.